# Integrating Amplitude Analytics to React Native App with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, analytics, amplitude-analytics

I am trying to integrate Amplitude to my React Native project. I am currently still developing the application and using Expo. The first event I am trying to capture is when a user is logged in.

```
const events = {
  USER_LOGGED_IN: 'USER_LOGGED_IN',
  USER_CREATED_ACCOUNT: 'USER_CREATED_ACCOUNT',
};
let isInitialized = false;
const apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const initialize = () => {
  if (!Environment.isProduction || !apiKey) {
    return;
  }

  Amplitude.initialize(apiKey);
  isInitialized = true;
};
```

In my render function (above the return) I have this line of code:

```
render() {
    Expo.Amplitude.logEvent('USER_LOGGED_IN')
return (
```

I am not seeing any events coming into amplitude. Is it possible to see events while using expo to run my code?

*Note- this code is in my home screen component*

Comment: I would recommend you put this logic in something like `componentDidMount`

Comment: unfortunately not seeing anything still @EdgarAroutiounian . Have you integrated amplitude into a project before?

Comment: not in my own personal apps but example source code is here: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/js/Api/Analytics.js

Answer (score 3):

You need to [publish your Expo app](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/publishing.html) to see the events on Amplitude because the integration works only on prod env. Once your app is published, you'll see the events on Amplitude dashboard with a small delay, usually 1 minute.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did for amplitude to work

```
expo install expo-analytics-amplitude
```

Analytics.js

```
import * as Amplitude from 'expo-analytics-amplitude'

let isInitialized = false
const apiKey = 'YOUR_KEY_HERE'

export const events = {
    HOME: 'HOME'
}

export function initialize() {
    if (isInitialized || !apiKey) {
        return
    }

    Amplitude.initialize(apiKey)
    isInitialized = true
}

export function track(event, options) {
    initialize()

    if (options) {
        Amplitude.logEventWithProperties(event, options)
    } else {
        Amplitude.logEvent(event)
    }
}

export default {
    events,
    initialize,
    track
}
```

Import in the file where you need tracking

```
import Analytics from '../auth/Analytics'

...

useEffect(() => {
  Analytics.track(Analytics.events.HOME)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the code above, I made a few minor updates. I will update this if I find a better way to fully integrate.

```
expo install expo-analytics-amplitude
```

```
import * as Amplitude from 'expo-analytics-amplitude'

let isInitialized = false
const apiKey = 'your API key'

export const events = {
    HOME: 'HOME'
}

export function initialize() {
    if (isInitialized || !apiKey) {
        return
    }

    Amplitude.initializeAsync(apiKey)
    isInitialized = true
}

export function track(event, options) {
    initialize()

    if (options) {
        Amplitude.logEventWithPropertiesAsync(event, options)
    } else {
        Amplitude.logEventAsync(event)
    }
}

export default {
    events,
    initialize,
    track
}
```

Import into the file you need tracking.
I initialized my connection to Amplitude in App.js.

```
  import Analytics from "./app/auth/Analytics"; 

  useEffect(() => {
   Analytics.initialize()
   Analytics.track(Analytics.events.HOME)
  }, []);
```